# jQuery autocomplete breaking page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery's autocomplete ui plugin.

It works exactly as I would expect it to, but when I click on a particular 'suggestion' it is hiding other elements on the page. Nothing directly related to it (e.g. child, parent, etc.)

To make debugging more complicated, I am working in an .hta file that is using some activex stuff - so I can't run it through firebug or chrome's inspect element.

Any suggestions on how I can go across crushing this bug?

As suggested, code:
It is the contentWrapper elements that are disappearing

```
<div id="menu">

    <div id="menuContent">
    <div class='tab'>
        <div id='searchTab' class='title clickable'>SEARCH</div>
        <span class='switchcontent'>
            <div id="searchBox" class="ui-widget">
                <input style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px;" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget-content" id="tags" style="width:200px;"></input>
                <span class="demo">
                <button id="search" style="height:25px;"></button>
                </span> 
            </div>

            <div id="resultBox" class="ui-helper-hidden">
                <div class="title">RESULTS:</div>
                <div id="results"></div>
                <input type="button" value="New Search" id="back"></input>
            </div>
            <br>
        </span >
    </div>

    <div class='tab'>
        <div id="buildingTab" class='title clickable'>DIRECTORY</div>
        <span class="switchcontent">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/populate-test.js"></script>
        </span>
    </div>


    </div>

</div>

<!--div id="modelViewerTitle" class="title">
    3D BUILDING VIEW
    <span id="modelButtons">
        <input class="navRight" type="image" id="help" src="images/helpCircle-up.png" width="25" height="25" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='images/helpCircle-over.png';" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='images/helpCircle-up.png';" value="Help" title="Help"/>
        <input class="navRight" type="image" id="orbit" src="images/nav_img/orbit.png" width="25" height="25" onclick="btnNav_Clicked(11)" value="Orbit" title="Orbit"/> 
        <input class="navRight" type="image" id="viewall" src="images/nav_img/view-all.png" width="25" height="25'" onclick="btnViewAll_Clicked()" value="View All" title="View All"/>
        <input class="navRight" type="image" id="zoombox" src="images/nav_img/zoom-box.png" width="25" height="25" onclick="btnNav_Clicked(12)" value="Zoom Box" title="Zoom Box"/>
        <input class="navRight" type="image" id="zoom" src="images/nav_img/zoom.png" width="25" height="25" onclick="btnNav_Clicked(7)" value="Zoom" title="Zoom"/>
        <input class="navRight" type="image" id="pan" src="images/nav_img/pan.png" width="25" height="25" onclick="btnNav_Clicked(9)" value="Pan" title="Pan"/>
        <input class="navRight" type="image" id="walk" src="images/nav_img/walk-on.png" width="25" height="25" onclick="btnNav_Clicked(3)" value="Walk" title="Walk"/>&nbsp;
    </span>
</div-->
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="modelViewer">
        <div id="model">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infoBox">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post some code, so we can make helpful suggestions.

Comment: have you tried debugging it with Firebug? You need to know if these elements are disappearing (display: none; or something) or are they deleted / moved out of the screen? There's a plenty of possibilities

Answer (score 1):

for me it sounds like you have the same "class" attribute set for multiple items. When jQuery Autocomplete tries to hide the completion list, it "catches" also the other items.

it's just a guess ... if you post some code, we might probably help you :)